# xcode8 interface builder shows titles and controls spread out vertically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My view controller has just a couple titles an buttons.
On my iPhone, they appear much closer vertically than in interface builder.

Comment: Provide some code and screenshots. Is your screen the same size as you have in interface builder?

Comment: Try to preview the result in Xcode [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/PreviewingYourUserInterface.html). You will be able to know if the problem appear at build time or if it's a conceptual problem

Comment: do you have default splash page sizes for all the iphones?